JCH - what do I enter to ignore scripts from an extension?
There's an issue with BreezingForms and JCH resulting in the former not showing a reCAPTCHA because JavaScript is moved to the bottom, as I managed to debug.
I don't want to disable the feature altogether. So I spotted this box in JCH settings:

where I would like to disable BreezingForms.
The problem is that the dropdown doesn't work and I have no idea what to enter there. This documentation specifies there should be folder name or domain, but where do I get these from? I tried e.g. breezingforms but that didn't do anything.

It's com_breezingforms, which is e.g. findable if you enter components folder in Joomla root.
Note that it only ignores scripts that are in a folder which has com_breezingforms as one of parents, not all scripts introduced by an extension. So e.g. 3rd party https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js will still get moved to the bottom.

Please Accept your answer as the correct solution.
